tex4ebook lists of figures, tables and listings can't be placed in backmatter, linking behavior is weirdI
I have some trouble with list of figures, list of tables and list of listings with tex4ebook (with pdflatex, everything behaves well). First of all, the lists appear at the beginning of the ebook and not at the end after the last chapter and before the index as the MWE LaTeX source suggests. The bibliography appears at the end how it should.
The links in the table of content also do not behave as they should. "List of Figures" links to the bibliography (wrong), "List of Tables" links to the list of tables (correct), "Listings" links to listings (correct), "Bibliography" links to the first chapter (wrong) and "Index" links to the index (correct).
The MWE looks like this:
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{%
  >={Latex[width=2mm,length=2mm]},
  % Specifications for style of nodes:
            base/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black,
                           minimum width=4cm, minimum height=1cm,
                           text centered, font=\sffamily},
  login/.style = {base, fill=blue!30},                         
}

\usepackage[formats]{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefineformat{C}{%
\{=\space\string\newline\indent,%
\}=[;]\newline\noindent\string\newline%
}

\usepackage[]{imakeidx}

\makeindex[intoc=true,columns=1,noautomatic]

\usepackage{tex4ebook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[hyperindex=true]{hyperref}

\bibliography{sample}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\chapter{First Chapter}


\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm,
      every node/.style={fill=white, font=\sffamily}, align=center]
  \centering
  % Specification of nodes (position, etc.)
    \node (login)         [login]                    {Login};
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \caption{Process diagram}
   \label{processDiagram}
 \end{figure}
\index{process digram}

\section{First Section}
  
\subsection{First Subsection}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Nordics Regions}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{Region Code} & \textbf{Country} & \textbf{Region Name}\\
\hline
03 & Norway & Oslo \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{nordicsRegions}
\end{table}
\index{nordics regions}

\chapter{Second Chapter}

Not only valid ones in listing \ref{applebug}.\footnote{quoted from \cite{apple:ssl}}\index{Appe SSL bug}

\begin{lstlisting}[float, language = C, frame = trBL, format = C, basicstyle = \ttfamily\small, keepspaces = true, caption = Apple's SSL/TLS Bug, label = applebug]

static OSStatus
SSLVerifySignedServerKeyExchange(
  SSLContext *ctx,
  bool isRsa, 
  SSLBuffer signedParams,
  uint8_t *signature,
  UInt16 signatureLen)
{
  OSStatus        err;
  ...
}
\end{lstlisting}

\backmatter

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\listoftables

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\lstlistlistingname}
\lstlistoflistings

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\printbibliography

\printindex

\end{document}

The bibliography file has this content:
@online {
    apple:ssl,
    author = {Apple},
    title = {sslKeyExchange},
    url = {https://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-55471/libsecurity_ssl/lib/sslKeyExchange.c},
    urldate = {2024-07-26}
}


I am vacations, so I can look at this at the beginning of January

Hi @michal.h21 thank you for noticing this issue! Have a nice vacation, you have very much deserved it.
